# Unable to run SSH through php on XAMPP in Linux

Tags: php, python, linux, ssh, xampp

I'm trying to run SSH in python through os.system() which is being invoked by PHP. It works fine when I run it through the CLI version of PHP but it is not running through lamp.

Following is my php code:

```
<?php $x=shell_exec('python test.py'); ?>
```

and below is the python code (test.py) which is being invoked by the PHP code:

```
import os
os.system("ssh test@127.0.0.1")
```

I also tried using touch utility through `exec()` in PHP, the same  thing happens.

Comment: Does it even get to the Python script? Can PHP find the Python interpreter? Is shell_exec() and exec() allowed per your configuration? You could try to debug by putting a print statement in the shell_exec() or exec() calls (or write to file if you want); if that works try a print statement in your python script and work from there.

Comment: @SaeX Yes, the php script is able to execute python, there were print statements in my python code, which were printing. exec() is able to execute commands like ls and ps on my system.

Comment: It may be running the ssh command with a different user than you're doing it from the CLI. Maybe the user running PHP doesn't have the servers key in its key file or something.

Comment: @RameshDahiya : Is it possible to run php as root?

Comment: Never do that. Its a suicide. Its always better to use built in functions. I dont know what you trying to accomplish using python script. But would suggest to use PHP inbuilt fucntions http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php.

Comment: @RameshDahiya : I'm getting [ Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ssh.php] when trying to connect via ssh2 through php. Can you tell me what package to install?

Comment: @PreetamBidhanRoyChoudhury follow php.net site for this http://php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Answer (score 1):

Use phpseclib. Using the ssh2 extension as recommended by @Ramesh Dahiya is bad for a number of reasons as elaborated here:

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/compare.html

Example of phpseclib being used:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```